# Cannot get Category value from a test case

Tags: c#, nunit, testrail

I am trying to get the Category value of a test case.  The test case has a category value of

```
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
    [Category("Smoke")]
    public class MSPSmokeTests : Base
    {

        [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(LoginDataZZ3))]
        [Category("C1879186")]
```

In my teardown method I try to access this category value and remove the 'C' value to store it to a var variable leaving just the number '1979186.

```
var testCase = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Category").ToString().Replace("C", "");
```

I get the following error when I run:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

NUnit.Framework.TestContext.PropertyBagAdapter.Get(...) returned null.

Is there wrong logic here or another way to do this?

The same code works in another part of the solution like so:

```
        [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(LoginDataZZ3))]
        [Category("C1879186")]
        public void UserCanClickOnAdministrationTileTest(string username, string password)
        {
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(GetDriver());
            MSPDashboard mspdashboard = new MSPDashboard(GetDriver());
            driver.Value.Navigate().GoToUrl(zz3);
            loginPage.CheckCookies();
            loginPage.EnterUserNameAndPassword(username, password);
            driver.Value.Navigate().GoToUrl($"{zz3}/msp/index");
            mspdashboard.adminTile.Click();
            string currentURL = driver.Value.Url;   
            StringAssert.Contains("/msp/orgs", currentURL);
        }
```

Teardown method:

```
        [TearDown]
        public async Task TearDown()
        {

        // arrange
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest($"index.php?/api/v2/get_runs/7&limit=1", Method.Get);
        string authInfo = Base64StringConverter.GetBase64String("email:password");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // act
        RestResponse<GetRun> response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<GetRun>(restRequest);
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;

        // assert
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetRun>>(response.Content);
        var a = data[0];
        var run = a.Id;

        var testCase = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Category").ToString().Replace("C", "");
        Console.WriteLine(testCase);
        var result = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        
        var testRailStatus = result switch
        {
            TestStatus.Failed => ResultStatus.Failed,
            TestStatus.Passed => ResultStatus.Passed,
            _ => ResultStatus.Retest
        };

        Console.WriteLine(testRailStatus.ToString());
        string status = testRailStatus.ToString();

        int status_id;
        if (status == "Passed")
        {
            status_id = 1;
        }
        else status_id = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(status_id);

        RestRequest addResult = new RestRequest($"index.php?/api/v2/add_result_for_case/{run}/{testCase}", Method.Post);
        addResult.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
        addResult.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        addResult.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        addResult.AddJsonBody(new { status_id = status_id });
        var newResponse = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(addResult);
    }
```

Comment: The error says everything here. The thing you are trying to access doesn't have an instance of that object. The object is null so you cannot access any of its properties.

Comment: This same code works correctly in another part of my solution though and the variable is assigned.  I have updated question with working code.

Comment: *This same code works correctly in another part of my solution* - Can we see the rest of the test? There might be something you're doing different that it making this difference into an error.

Comment: Updated code to include full test.

Comment: Can I also get the other test too... Also your tests are super messy and unstructured. My recommendation is to use [Given_When_Then](https://www.newthings.co/blog/structuring-tests-using-given-when-then/) e.g. `GivenSomeContext_WhenUserHasClickedOnAdministrationTile_ThenWhatYouExpectTheOutComeToBe`. Also this sounds like a UI test rather then a unit test to me as you're testing a button.

Comment: And also does "Category" even exist in the other context? Have you checked that?

Comment: @aidan The part that "works" isn't doing the same thing. I.e. it isn't accessing the category. Also, can you show your complete teardown method, not just the single line?

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist Yes the failing one is a UI test.  The one that passes is an API test.

Comment: @Charlie Added complete Teardown method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting category value because its not set correctly. Correct way to set category when using TestCaseSource is as below:

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
[Category("Smoke")]
public class MSPSmokeTests : Base
{

    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(LoginDataZZ3), Category = "C1234")]
    public void TestMethod1(string username, string password)
    {
    }
}
```

Also note that [TearDown] is performed after each test method, so make sure Category is set for each TestCases else it will fail for cases where its not set.

**Update**
You can also add multiple categories to a test case as below:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(LoginDataZZ3), Category = "C1234, FrontEndTests")]
```

And then can be read as:

```
var categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Category"].ToList();
Console.WriteLine(categories[0]);
Console.WriteLine(categories[1]);
```

Comment: That works now.  How would I add two categories to a single test?  E.g. "C1234" and "Smoke"

Comment: @Shah Good catch! Nobody saw that.

Comment: @Aidan Yes you can add two categories to single test. You need to pass it as comma separated values. I have updated the answer.